# Arriving at Frankfurt Hahn late at night, how do I get to the city?

Tags: airport-transfer, cancellations, frankfurt, hhn

I've made an error in judgement and have booked my Ryanair flight to Frankfurt (HAHN, I didn't think RyanAir would take me this far out of a city!). It was cheap and I regret my decision now. The problem is that I arrive in Frankfurt Hahn airport (a good 90mins drive from the city) at 9:15PM.

The only buses I can see are around 12AM or 2AM. This means a BIG gap at the airport and I'm not exactly sure if it's legal for me to linger that long? I can linger until 2AM if I need to.

Alternatively I can just book another flight and say good bye to my relatively cheap ticket goodbye... but that seems more expensive than to just sleep at the expensive hotels at the airport. Can I even get out of this flight? It's for the 29th of September and with RyanAir. Sorry, it is my first time flying in Europe.

Note: I'm on a budget, taxis, private hires, etc are out. I'd rather wait for 5 hours in the dark than hire something that's going to break my bank.

Comment: My German is at zero, but from [this page](http://flyhahn.com/frankfurt-hahn-airport/frankfurt-am-main-frankfurt-hahn-airport-bus-route-timetable.htm) I can deduce that there are some bus connections from Hahn to Frankfurt central train station at 10pm, 11pm, midnight, then 00:30 and so on.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I saw that too. Based on that information alone it looks like I'd be perfectly fine. What should I do at the other end though? I highly doubt any hostels would accept that late an entry right?

Comment: I'm not sure honestly.  It could be a good idea to call a couple of them and find out.  If you catch the 10pm bus, you'll be in the city centre around midnight. It's not too late for hostels.

Comment: Looks like those late buses also halt in Mainz Hbf, which should be about half an hour _before_ Frankfurt Hbf, and give you a bit more time, if you can find accommodation in Mainz for the first night.

Comment: Legal? Why would it not be legal? You have a perfectly valid reason to be there (waiting for a bus). Confused...

Comment: I have never flown European small airports, but in Australia, waiting outside an airport would be really suspicious at like 10pm->2am.

Comment: @insidesin Waiting for a bus after arriving on a scheduled flight at a time when buses are infrequent is not remotely suspicious. The worst case is that somebody asks what you're doing and you tell them that your flight arrived at time X and you're waiting for the next bus, which isn't until time Y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I arrive in Frankfurt Hahn airport (a good 90mins drive from the city) at 9:15PM.

No worries! The HHN airport is indeed far from Frankfurt, but the connections are not *that* bad. Just take the 10.30 pm bus. Ticket for an adult is 15€ (14€ if you buy it online).

You find the bus schdules via the airport's official site: [Getting there - by bus](http://www.hahn-airport.de/default.aspx?menu=by_bus&cc=en#). Click Frankfurt on the map and [**this timetable page**](http://www.bohr.de/linienverkehr/buslinie-hahn-frankfurt) opens ([English translation via Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=fi&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bohr.de%2Flinienverkehr%2Fbuslinie-hahn-frankfurt&edit-text=&act=url)).

September 29 is Tuesday, and the last departures from the airport are:

```
Dienstag, Abfahrt Hahn - Ankunft Frankfurt

Hahn Terminal B Frankfurt Airport   Frankfurt Hbf

[...]

20:00           21:30               21:45
22:30           00:15               00:30
23:30           01:15               01:30

00:00           01:45               02:00
00:30           02:15               02:30
```

(Note that departures at/after midnight are shown in the next day's—in this case Wednesday's—timetable.)

Comment: So what do I do at midnight afterwards, do hostels open that late, will any accept me?

Comment: There are lots of hostels with 24/7 reception, so I don’t think it should be a problem. Just make sure when reserving that it’s ok. I once stayed at [Five Elements](http://www.hostelworld.com/hosteldetails.php/Five-Elements-Hostel-Frankfurt/Frankfurt/27373) and liked it; they have 24 hour reception. (Any further doubts about accommodation, post a new question.)

Comment: Talked to the hostel I wanted to stay at, they're more than happy to take me at midnight. :)